# How do I specify fixed width for material card titles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am trying to give two material cards a fixed title height, regardless of how much content they have. I would like the height of the cards to be 15px but for some reason they won't adjust.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  .demo-card-square > .mdl-card__title {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 50px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-grid">

    <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Box</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          View Updates
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Box</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          View Updates
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing class "mdl-card--expand" is another way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by also specifying a maximum height on the card.

```
max-height: 50px;
```